# Set HTML5 Video source programmatically after page load

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I have an empty video element on page load that gets populated after an AJAX call but the video isn't loading.

If I hardcode the video source to be "/video/get?id=12" then the video file is retrieved and the user can play it on the page.

However, I want to be able to set the video source using jQuery (some time after the page has finished loading). I've tried setting the source elements src parameter but with no luck. I've also tried appending an entire to the video tag but still no good.

Calling load() or play() or both on the video tag doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks to anyone who can help on this.

EDIT: If I set a div's content using .html() to be the entire video tag then the video can play, but only in Chrome. IE seems to submit the request but Firefox does nothing...

Answer (score -1):

I created a fiddle with live demo take a look at this.

http://jsfiddle.net/VZHdW/

Make sure that the browser in which you are testing supports HTML5.

Comment: Doesn't work for me I'm afraid - no request submitted to my RESTful Web Service in either Chrome or Firefox...